# Bootstrap Grid System does not work inside mat-expansion-panel

Tags: angular, layout, bootstrap-4, angular-material

When using the Boostrap 4 grid system inside the Angular/Material `mat-expansion-panel`, the grid elements do not fit into the grid. All elements in a row do not fit and the last element carries over to a new line.

Answer (score 9):

The Bootstrap grid system expects all elements to have the `box-sizing` set to `border-box`. To fix this just add the following css to your page.

```
.mat-expansion-panel{
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

for all elements in a row, obviously have col-* class, add this style:

```
col-* {  box-sizing: border-box;}
```